# Pre-configure Contact Form 7 inside a WordPress theme

Tags: contact-form-7

I really like the capabilities of Contact Form 7.

Does anyone know if there is a way to incorporate Contact Form 7 into a commercial theme without the user having to create the form himself by going in the plugin settings and then obtaining an ID for the shortcode?

The desired functionality is for the user to simply use my theme's page template. The custom Contact Form to be programmed inside the template file.

It is important to not use any plugin hacks, so that plugin upgrades will not break the functionality.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Something like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) offers. In the plugin settings they have a feature called "Export Field Groups to PHP". It generates the code which you can paste in your theme. However this plugin is not meant for contact forms (I don't think). It would be great to know how to do that with Contact Form 7.